# Hyper-linking moving objects within an image?

Tags: html, image, dynamic, hyperlink, imagemap

I want to know if it is possible to create an image with hyper-links inside, such as one would make for a HTML image-map but with the hyper-linked objects actively moving around within the boundaries of the 'image-map'?

For instance i may want a few click-able hyperlinked squares that fly around within a circle. I'm basically looking to create entertainment/amusing difficulty for someone trying to navigate to the other pages of my website from the homepage; a very dynamic menu you could say.

Would it be possible to plot co-ordinated routes for the objects [that don't clash] and then instead of defining individual static co-ordinates as the locations, input the co-ordinate route? Haven't a clue what language/script this would be done with [if it can be], preferably one that ain't too hard to learn and is supported by modern-browsers. Only know basic/intermediate HTML 4.01 and CSS/3 at the moment.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. Have you tried it yourself yet? Hint: CSS3 can probably do it (floating elements + animations).

Comment: Think you've hit the nail on the head. Need to up my game in the CSS3 department it seems; never knew 'bout this magical world of crazy animation! Cheers.

Comment: If you can create a vague idea of what you want in [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/), I/we can probably help you with what issues you run into.